# shell script: ftp to check existing file

Tags: linux, shell

I've a simple shell script to transfer daily log file to another Windows FTP.

The problem is if the file is already there, it will still uploading a new one even though the file name is exactly the same.

How to perform a quick check on this script? If the file is there, then it won't proceed with FTP transfer

```
ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
bin
mput $FILE
bye
EOT
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy in `Unix` with `ftp`. First login to the system through `ftp` and run a `ls -ltr` command through `ftp` and list the files in a `history.txt` file(see below my example) and while transferring the file first check whether that file is already available in history file or not. And if available do not transfer that file. I do it like below:-

```
HISTORY_FILE="history.txt"

ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
bin
ls -rtE $HISTORY_FILE
bye
EOT
```

Now you can use below command to check:-

```
ISFILENAMEEXIST=$(cat $HISTORY_FILE | grep $FILE)
```

Now if the file exist in `history.txt`, do not send that file and if not available send it through `ftp`.